# can I schedule an ansible playbook to run at a certain time everyday

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ansible, yaml

I have an ansible playbook in yaml to start a service in a host server.
can I schedule it to run at a certain time everyday?
Also will cron work for it?

Answer (score 0):

`ansible-playbook` is a command, like `cp` or any other.

So yes, you can add it as cron job and set desired schedule for it.